# How to move a Rails one to many association to a one to one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

User model has_many Companies and Company belongs_to a User.

I now want to change this to a user has_one Company and Company has_one/belongs_to association. I have changed the models to look like this:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :company #was has_many
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
    has_many        :employees, inverse_of: :company
    has_many        :quotes, inverse_of: :company
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true #, :reject_if => lambda { |e| e.first_name.blank? }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :quotes, allow_destroy: true

    validates_presence_of :user, :co_name, :co_number, :postcode
    validates :co_name, length: { minimum: 2, message: "minimum of 2 chars" }
    validates :co_number, format: { with: /\A([1-9]\d{6,7}|\d{6,7}|(SC|NI|AC|FC|GE|GN|GS|IC|IP|LP|NA|NF|NL|NO|NP|NR|NZ|OC|R|RC|SA|SF|SI|SL|SO|SP|SR|SZ|ZC|)\d{6,8})\z/,
                message: "must be valid company number" }
    validates :postcode, format: { with: /\A(?:gir(?: *0aa)?|[a-pr-uwyz](?:[a-hk-y]?[0-9]+|[0-9][a-hjkstuw]|[a-hk-y][0-9][abehmnprv-y])(?: *[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2})?)\z/,
                message: "must be valid postcode" }

    enum industry:          [ :financial_services, :architect, :business_consultancy ]
end
```

and have `rake db:reset` and have changed this line in my Companies#create method:

```
@company = current_user.companies.new(company_params)
```

to

```
@company = current_user.company.new(company_params)
```

But I'm getting a

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

and I can't see where I'm going wrong. `current_user` should be available? the has_one association is defined so I should be able to call company.new on it right? I don;t need a foreign_key added to User, or do I?

Can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try `@company = current_user.build_company(company_params)` instead

Comment: Great @pavan, that works now, whats the difference between `.build_company` and `.company.new' can you tell me? (Put above as answer please and I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

For `has_one`, you should use `build_association` method, so

```
@company = current_user.company.new(company_params)
```

should be

```
@company = current_user.build_company(company_params)
```

Here is a list of all [*available methods*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for `has_one` association